# index advice - multiple columns or identity

Tags: database-design

I have table below and was wondering on best index approach to use. Table will not join to any other tables although foreign keys have been included in case that requirement is required at a later date. Table will be a summary table for a single report and currently the only clustered index i can think of using is composite and contains quite a few columns as this is the only way to end up with a unique value, is it worth using an identity key and using that as my index? i have also created some non-clustered index's on various singular columns that will be used as parameters on my report.

any advice would be very welcome as my index knowledge isn't fantastic could you plese provide an explanation.

```
table 
     [AccountingPeriod] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [reportPeriod] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [NewRenewal] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [MovementTypeGroup] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [Year] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [Quarter] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Month] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [BranchId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [BranchKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BranchDescription] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductDescription] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UgId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [UgKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UnderwritingGroup] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ActualGBP] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [ActualEUR] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [ActualUSD] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [PlanGBP] [money] NOT NULL,
    [PlanEUR] [float] NOT NULL,
    [PlanUSD] [float] NOT NULL,
    [PriorGBP] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriorEUR] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriorUSD] [int] NOT NULL
```

index

FlashreportPeriod, NewRenewal, BranchDescription, ProductDescription, UnderwritingGroup, DWAccountingPeriod, MovementTypeGroup

Comment: Can you provide more of a context? What requirements do you have? Are you going to do a lot of inserts or updates and how important is performance of these? And how about deletes? In general, how are you going to use this table?

Comment: the table will be truncated and repopulated each evening and once populated will have an update statement run against it for the prior values but will be used for select/reporting purposes only during the day

Answer (score 0):

The best index strategy is to delay index design until such time as it's needed.  For foreign keys, you've explicitly ruled them out for the present.  An index costs you time at insert and update time, and saves you time at query time.  What kinds of queries are you going to be doing?  What is the relative frequency and relative urgency of each query?  That will guide you towards the right indexes to support simple queries.

Having said all that, there is a reason why you should declare a primary key for the table.  A table with no primary key is vulnerable to duplicates, and duplicates are a real mess at the logical level (see First Normal Form).  If you do declare a primary key,  any decent DBMS will build an index for you that catalogs the same columns as the primary key.

That index is needed, at the very least, to detect duplicates at insert time.  It may help with queries as well.  It sounds like your PK is going to include AccountingPeriod.  That will make the index most useful for queries involving AccountingPeriod.